# .NET MAUI Handler to change toolbar font

Tags: maui

I am trying to change the color and font of the toolbar title. Created the following handler but it is not making any chance.

```cs
ToolbarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Toolbar.Title), (h, v) =>
{
    var materialToolbar = h.PlatformView;
        
    materialToolbar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
    {
        ForegroundColor = Colors.Orange.ToPlatform(),
        Font = UIFont.FromName("Poppins", 25)
    };
});
```

I am using the latest .NET 7 and observing this issue on IOS.

Are there any obvious problems ? Or else, how can I troubleshoot further ?

Comment: What do you mean by "toolbar" here? It would be helpful to see a screenshot or mockup of what you would like to change. Do you only need this on iOS or MacCatalyst?

Comment: If you mean the title bar, you don't need to use a handler, you can also [customize the title bar](https://blog.ewers-peters.de/customize-the-title-bar-of-a-maui-app-with-these-simple-steps) using a custom title view.

Comment: Thanks @Julian ! Yes, I am after changing the title of the page. Currently using `<Shell.TitleView>` already. However, what happens is that when I move across pages, the normal title and back button loads first and the one I want to display comes a moment later, terrible from a UX perspective. Happy to hear if your experience has been different.

Comment: I haven't observed that kind of behavior so far. Are you using the latest .NET version?

Comment: Latest 7, basically there is a slight delay between page loading and TitleView getting updated. More prominent on simulators, but definitely noticeable on the phone as well. That's why I was trying to do it using a handler so that the page it self get loaded correctly rather than first loading it and then modifying it.

Comment: It is on IOS, updated the original question to that effect.

Comment: Did another test, created a basic 2 page project to make sure it wasn't the constructors etc causing the delay, it is still the same issue. Then I decided to give it a go with .NET 8 preview and problem disappeared, they must have fixed something.